# Php multiple photo upload and rename

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

My problem recently arose when I tried to change save a picture to a location with a different name. eg. saving a picture called hello.jpg to a location called /sets/1/09092014-1.jpg

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
$file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
$file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
$file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
$file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
$today = date("dmY");
$Title =  $today."-".$x.".jpg";
$x ++;
$url = "/Sets/".$desired_dir."/".$Title;

$query = "INSERT INTO photo(name, url, album) VALUES('$Title', '$url', '$set')";
$result = mysql_query($query) OR DIE(mysql_error());


if($file_size > 10485760){
$errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
}
if(empty($errors)==true){
if(is_dir("Sets/"."$desired_dir")==false){
mkdir("Sets/"."$desired_dir", 0700);
}
if(is_dir("Sets/"."$desired_dir/".$Title)==false){
rename ($file_tmp ,  $Title );
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "/Sets/$desired_dir/$file_tmp");
}else{
}
```

not including the DB stuff at the top.

I spent a while on this, and found that i may need to use the rename() method to rename the file before i save it, which I tried, but once again it didnt work.

When run, it adds the info to the database, creates the folder to be put in if not present, but then does not add the files.

Thanks,
Waq

Comment: do you have a `Sets` directory in the root of your server's filesystem? REmember that PHP operates at the fileystem level, and has absolutely NO knowledge of your site's structure. if `/Sets` is actually a web path, then you'd probably need something more like `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/Sets/etc...'` instead for your move_uploaded_file() calls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The /Sets file is among the php files that I am working from. I thought that it was working as if /Sets/1/ isn't present, it will create the "1" folder inside /Sets/. Is move_uploaded_file() different?

Comment: so you have `example.com/Sets/blahblahblah`? Then that's a web-based path, and exists somewhere down inside your server's filesystem, probably `/home/sites/example.com/html/Sets` or whatever. You need that ENTIRE path, since PHP won't know you're trying to stay withing your site's document root. php couldn't care less what your site's document root is.

Comment: I changed the move_uploaded_file() line to this: 
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/Sets/$desired_dir/$file_tmp"); But that did not add the file still. Was that what you thought I should add?

Comment: That was just an example. You haven't explained at all what your server's file structure/layout it. You also have no error handling at all, and are simply assuming that the upload and move operations should be succeeding.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/1331ac0aaaa444bdedad9e91a6dfe23d Here is what my file system looks like :) The issue that I'm having only happened when I tried to change the name of the file. I just tried a few things, the document_root thing takes me up to my /hub . So I added /Backend/ to the rest. But still no luck adding the photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your explanation you should not need to use $_SERVER["DOCUMENTE_ROOT"] at all. You just need to pay attention to file structure and your code. Here is corrected code with comments:

```
if(empty($errors)==true){
// $desired_dir didn't need parenthesis, buts its ok to use them
// Remember directories and file names are case sensitive: Sets is != to sets
if(is_dir("Sets/".$desired_dir)==false){
// If your server is picky you can try 0755 here and change it lower later
mkdir("Sets/".$desired_dir, 0700);
}
// ERROR your if test is supplying a file but you were testing for directory
// $Title is a file not a directory
if(is_file("Sets/".$desired_dir."/".$Title)==false){
rename ($file_tmp,$Title);
// You just renamed $file_tmp so change the blow code to use the right file
// Because of the rename $file_tmp no longer exists
move_uploaded_file($Title,"Sets/$desired_dir/$Title");
}else{
// It already exists, handle it
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some reason it is still only creating the files in the /Backend folder instead of /Backend/Sets/1. Thanks for the comments, really helped walk me through it. I thought the rename function would have changed the content of the $file_tmp not just rename it.

Comment: Ya rename() is a function that uses the variables you give it to perform its task. So when you used it, technically $file_tmp still exists, the problem is its holding a value (the old file name) that doesn't exist on the server anymore so; just had to clarify. Oh...I see the error I think its in the move_uploaded_file() I have a slash in front of Sets that shouldn't be there. Fixed the code.

Comment: Yeah I eventually removed that slash after playing about with your original answer! Thanks so much for your help, works great now.